# jQuery Traversing For Parent Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble traversing to find a certain element. I have the following html:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="example" class="col-sm-2">Example</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="example" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I can select the input example, and I would like to select the contents of label, so it would be "Example". I can't do parent().parent() because since I'm using bootstrap, if I had a radio or a select, the tree would be different. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can target it with [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.form-control').closest('.form-group').find('label:eq(0)').text()
```

**OR**

```
$('.form-control').closest('div').prev('label').text()
```

**OR**

```
$('.form-control').closest('div').siblings('label').text()
```

Comment: Ahh thanks! I was trying $('.form-control').closest('label') but that didn't work.

Comment: I don't think the second one would work because as stated, if I had a radio form-group, it would be like this: `<label for="itemize-supplies-amount[]" class="col-sm-1">Amount</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
    <input type="text" name="itemize-supplies-amount[]" class="form-control itemize-supplies-amount">
    <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
   </div>
  </div>`

Comment: @ashin999 then you need to provide specific class like this `$('.form-control').closest('div.col-sm-3').prev('label').text()`

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's .closest();

More info on their documentation page which can be found here: [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)